# Split emscripten generated file

Tags: javascript, generated-code, emscripten

I have a *very* big Javascript file (> 50MB) generated by Emscripten (Debug mode).

Debugging this file is a pain in the browser. A solution would be to split the file in several small files. Loading time is no issue, because it is a debug build.

Any idea how to do this? I tried every function in a separate file but some functions reference other functions and then the load order of the JS files becomes relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I made a pull request against Emscripten to add this function. Feel free to use it:
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/594